# "!=" and "is blank" not working as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you please help me correct me app script code?

```
function sendEmails() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow ();
  

  for (var i=2;i<=lr;i++)
  {

    var currentemail =ss.getRange (i,1).getValue();
    var currentclasstitle =ss.getRange (i,3).getValue();
    var currentcondition =ss.getRange (i,4).getValue();
    var Confirmation =ss.getRange (i,4).setValue("Email Sent");

    if (currentcondition!="Email Sent"&& currentemail !=""){

    MailApp.sendEmail(currentemail,currentclasstitle+ " Invoice Request Updates ","Hi");}
    else if (currentemail!="") {Confirmation}
  }
  
}
```

everything not showing correctly after else if statement

what I want is

**

- IF A3 is BLANK I WANT D3 also to be BLANK

**

as per my above code, even if A3 is blank D3 populates email sent

[image: Google SS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're setting value in `D3` before your `If` statement

Replace this:-

```
    var Confirmation =ss.getRange (i,4).setValue("Email Sent");

    if (currentcondition!="Email Sent"&& currentemail !=""){

    MailApp.sendEmail(currentemail,currentclasstitle+ " Invoice Request Updates ","Hi");}
    else if (currentemail!="") {Confirmation}
```

with this:-

```
    const confirmation = ss.getRange (i,4)
    if (currentemail !== "" && currentcondition !== "Email Sent" )
    {      
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentemail,currentclasstitle+ " Invoice Request Updates ","Hi");
      confirmation.setValue("Email Sent");
    }
```

Reference:

[if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Many thanks @vector for pointing wrong scope ,                                                                      
 however if have two conditions , i want email to be sent only if column D IS EMPTY and Column A IS NOT empty and after sending, mark column D as "Email Sent" , if there is blank row in column A it should NOT SAY "email sent "                                                                    hence i had tried if (currentcondition!="Email Sent"&& currentemail !="")   this did work, but it also populated column D as "Email Sent" although no email was sent for cell A3

Comment: This is exactly happening above, if  `Column A` is not empty than it will send email and set value in `Column D` as Email Sent, and if  `Column A` is empty it will sent value in `Column D` is blank, I've not added this `currentcondition!="Email Sent"` because you're setting value in that when `currentemail !=""` gets satisfied, according to me it won't make any difference, but you can add that in above sample code, and try it and lemme know if it works or not!

Comment: Thanks a lot @vector As per the code you have updated, cell D2 (please see screenshot) which has value “Email Sent” is overwritten as “blank” . I want D2 to stay the same . Because it implies that email is already sent

Comment: @luisC in that case try latest modification

Comment: this is working , many thanks , only one email was sent , D2 was not overwritten and D3 was left blank

Comment: @luisC Thanks, for confirming it. You can also accept this answer for the documentation purpose.